# ggplot2 - line plot by year-quarter on the x axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series, rstudio

I am trying to use ggplot2 for the following. I am looking for line chart, but running in to issues. I have two related questions.

1.)

```
 df = read.table(text = "bank  filer    id  quarter year    loan    assets
 year qtr yearqtr code assets
 2001 1   2001-1    51       39007.16
 2001 2   2001-2    51       83337.32
 2001 3   2001-3    51      133618.83
 2001 4   2001-4    51      211263.55
 2002 1   2002-1    51       68034.41
 2002 3   2002-2    51      134005.24
 2002 3   2002-3    51      203544.39
 2002 4   2002-4    51      274482.43
 2003 1   2003-1    51       63188.83"
, sep ="", header = TRUE)
```

First I am looking to plot assets by yearqtr -- yearqtr formed by concatenate

```
  year and qtr.
```

To plot by quarter I have the following code:

```
 myplot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=yearqtr, y=assets))  + geom_line()

 myplot <- myplot + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor =         element_blank(),  panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

But I get

```
 geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

I wonder if it is due to that yearqtr is not number? What would be the issue?

My question 2.) is how do we show that  how do I plot the quarter values of the asset, but then on the x-axis just show 2000, 2001, 2002, ...  This is because since I have 2001-1, 2001-2, ... , 2014-1. The x-axis looks very crowded, so I am trying to see if I can display something like

2000  2001   2003 and then have the quarter values displayed in between them.

Thank you so much. appreciate any advice.

Comment: What happened when you googled/searched SO for the error message?

Comment: try: `ggplot(data = df, aes(x=yearqtr, y=assets, group=1))  + geom_line()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
myplot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=yearqtr, y=assets, group=1)) +
  geom_line()
myplot <- myplot + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-45, hjust=0.001))
myplot
```

[image]

Comment: About your question 2, don't think it's a good idea to just showing 2000, ... which not informative.  You could always adjust the "angle" or "tilting" of the labels if the space is too busy.

Comment: That did the trick. I used combination of    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-45, hjust=0.001)) and scale_axis_discrete specifying the break points as 1st quarters of every year.